# Haskell / Miranda: Find the type of the function

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference, miranda

**Brief:**  This is a past exam question from a Miranda exam but the syntax is very similar to Haskell.

**Question:**  What is the type of the following expression and what does it do? (The definitions
of the functions length and swap are given below).

```
(foldr (+) 0) . (foldr ((:) . length . (swap (:) [] )) [])

length [] = 0

length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs

swap f x y = f y x
```

*Note:*

Please feel free to reply in haskell syntax - sorry about putting using the stars as polytypes but i didn't want to translate it incorrectly into haskell.  Basically, if one variable has type * and the other has * it means they can be any type but they must both be the same type.  If one has ** then it means that it can but does not need to have the same type as *.  I think it corresponds to a,b,c etc in haskell usuage.

**My working so far**

From the definition of length you can see that it finds the length of a list of anything so this gives

```
length :: [*] -> num.
```

From the definition I think swap takes in a function and two parameters and produces the function with the two parameters swapped over, so this gives

```
swap :: (* -> ** -> ***) -> ** -> [*] -> ***
```

foldr takes a binary function (like plus) a starting value and list and folds the list from right to left using that function.  This gives

```
foldr :: (* -> ** -> **) -> ** -> [*] -> **)
```

I know in function composition it is right associative so for example everything to the right of the first dot (.) needs to produce a list because it will be given as an argument to the first foldr.

The foldr function outputs a single value ( the result of folding up the list) so I know that the return type is going to be some sort of polytype and not a list of polytype.

**My problem**

I'm unsure where to go from here really.  I can see that swap needs to take in another argument, so does this partial application imply that the whole thing is a function?  I'm quite confused!

Comment: Just install the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) and use GHCi to test it, what's the problem? `Prelude> let swap = flip`   `Prelude> :t (foldr (+) 0) . (foldr ((:) . length . (swap (:) [] )) [])`   
`(foldr (+) 0) . (foldr ((:) . length . (swap (:) [] )) [])
  :: [a] -> Int`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I was hoping to get some help with understanding how to get there too!  Though knowing the answer will definitely help me try to figure out a route there so thanks again

Comment: Well, you can test any subexpression of the complete one in GHCi, that should pretty well give you understanding of the way to get there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already got the answer, I'll just write down the derivation step by step so it's easy to see all at once:

```
xxf xs = foldr (+) 0 . foldr ((:) . length . flip (:) []) [] $ xs
       = sum         $ foldr ((:) . length . (: []))      []   xs
       = sum         $ foldr (\x -> (:) (length [x]))     []   xs
       = sum         $ foldr (\x r ->    length [x]:r)    []   xs
       = sum         $ map   (\x   ->    length [x]  )         xs
       = sum                            [length [x]  |    x <- xs]  
       = sum                            [ 1          |    x <- xs]
--     = length xs
xxf :: (Num n) => [a] -> n
```

So that, in Miranda, `xxf xs = #xs`. I guess its type is `:: [*] -> num` in Miranda syntax.

Haskell's `length` is `:: [a] -> Int`, but as defined here, it is `:: (Num n) => [a] -> n` because it uses `Num`'s `(+)` and two literals, `0` and `1`.

If you're having trouble visualizing `foldr`, it is simply

```
foldr (+) 0 (a:(b:(c:(d:(e:(...:(z:[])...))))))
      =      a+(b+(c+(d+(e+(...+(z+ 0)...)))))
      = sum [a, b, c, d, e, ..., z]
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's go through this step-by-step.

The `length` function obviously has the type that you described; in Haskell it's `Num n => [a] -> n`. The equivalent Haskell function is [`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:length) (It uses `Int` instead of any `Num n`).

The `swap` function takes a function to invoke and reverses its first two arguments. You didn't get the signature quite right; it's `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`. The equivalent Haskell function is [`flip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:flip).

The `foldr` function has the type that you described; namely `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. The equivalent Haskell function is [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldr).

Now, let's see what each sub expression in the main expression means.

The expression `swap (:) []` takes the `(:)` function and swaps its arguments. The `(:)` function has type `a -> [a] -> [a]`, so `swap`ping it yields `[a] -> a -> [a]`; the whole expression thus has type `a -> [a]` because the swapped function is applied to `[]`. What the resulting function does is that it constructs a list of one item given that item.

For simplicity, let's extract that part into a function:

```
singleton :: a -> [a]
singleton = swap (:) []
```

Now, the next expression is `(:) . length . singleton`. The `(:)` function still has type `a -> [a] -> [a]`; what the `(.)` function does is that it composes functions, so if you have a function `foo :: a -> ...` and a function `bar :: b -> a`, `foo . bar` will have type `b -> ...`. The expression `(:) . length` thus has type `Num n => [a] -> [n] -> [n]` (Remember that `length` returns a `Num`), and the expression `(:) . length . singleton` has type `Num => a -> [n] -> [n]`. What the resulting expression does is kind of strange: given any value of type `a` and some list, it will ignore the `a` and prepend the number `1` to that list.

For simplicity, let's make a function out of that:

```
constPrependOne :: Num n => a -> [n] -> [n]
constPrependOne = (:) . length . singleton
```

You should already be familiar with `foldr`. It performs a right-fold over a list using a function. In this situation, it calls `constPrependOne` on each element, so the expression `foldr constPrependOne []` just constructs a list of ones with equal length to the input list. So let's make a function out of that:

```
listOfOnesWithSameLength :: Num n => [a] -> [n]
listOfOnesWithSameLength = foldr constPrependOne []
```

If you have a list `[2, 4, 7, 2, 5]`, you'll get `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` when applying `listOfOnesWithSameLength`.

Then, the `foldr (+) 0` function is another right-fold. It is equivalent to the [`sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:sum) function in Haskell; it sums the elements of a list.

So, let's make a function:

```
sum :: Num n => [n] -> n
sum = foldr (+) 0
```

If you now compose the functions:

```
func = sum . listOfOnesWithSameLength
```

... you get the resulting expression. Given some list, it creates a list of equal length consisting of only ones, and then sums the elements of that list. It does in other words behave exactly like `length`, only using a much slower algorithm. So, the final function is:

```
inefficientLength :: Num n => [a] -> n
inefficientLength = sum . listOfOnesWithSameLength
```